# Save user information DialogFlow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

I am starting in `Dialogflow` and I would like to know if the information I keep from a user in a database, be it `Firebase`, that this information could occupy it to put it in a web page.
An example is the user's email stored in the database to be able to put it in a page where I am asked to enter with mail so that the user does not have to manually enter it that `Dialogflow` does.
What I am looking for with `Dialogflow` is to make the user able to pay from the created chat of `Dialogflow` in a web page only entering once his data and that the application does the rest collecting the saved data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Actions on Google, you can use a feature to [store user information](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#nodejs):

```
function simpleResponse(conv) {
  conv.user.storage.count = 1;
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about ' +
      'almost any number, like 42. What do you have in mind?',
    text: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any ' +
      'number. What do you have in mind?',
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. a question already saved this information Can I occupy to put it in a web page? like the mail

Comment: No, if you wanted to use this data outside of Actions on Google you'd need to store it in a different system like a database